# Can't change color of column that i subclass it

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nstextfieldcell

I subclass my table's column to `NStextFieldCell`. When I want to change column's color with below given code, color doesn't change. Why?

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    if(row%2==0)
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[NSColor knobColor]];
    else
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[NSColor lightGrayColor]];

    [cell setDrawsBackground: YES];
}
```

I use this code in `NSTextFieldCell` subclass

```
- (NSRect)titleRectForBounds:(NSRect)theRect 
{
    NSRect titleFrame = [super titleRectForBounds:theRect];
    NSSize titleSize = [[self attributedStringValue] size];
    titleFrame.origin.y = theRect.origin.y + (theRect.size.height - titleSize.height) / 2.0;
    return titleFrame;
}

- (void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView 
{
    NSRect titleRect = [self titleRectForBounds:cellFrame];
    [[self attributedStringValue] drawInRect:titleRect];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
[cell contentView] setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Not UIColor, but NSColor, because it's OSX not iOS.

Comment: i use it in `willDisplayCell` doesn't work (occur error in run time,means table doesn't show any rows)

Comment: what error exactly? how many rows does your table have? logs/screens?